An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: 'into' is a reserved word and may not appear in your query
An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: 'into' is a reserved word and may not appear in your query.
My Query:
select A.CARD_NUM AS CardNumber , B.PHONE AS MOBILE,

CASE
    WHEN A.CATEGORY='KIDS BOYS' THEN 'Revamp your boys wardrobe with the latest summer collection from Boys Fashion!\nExplore trendy styles in-store or online today!'

WHEN A.CATEGORY='KIDS GIRLS' THEN 'We invites all little queens to transform summer **into** a snowland with our stylish summer collection starting from just Rs.169.\nShop now!'
ELSE 'The quantity is under 30' END AS MESSAGE,

CONCAT(A.CARD_NUM,'_','fthh_auto','_',convert(varchar,cast(switchoffset(todatetimeoffset(GETDATE(),'-06:00'),'+05:30') as datetime),23))AS UniqueKey
from fthh_automation_load A
inner join
PRD_Contact_List B
on
A.CARD_NUM=B.CARD_NUM

In the SMS script for KIDS GIRLS there is an into word present because of this I'm getting a reserved word error.
Please can anyone let me know how I can overcome this error.
Thanks in advance.

It is a pretty messy practice to actual content into your sql; So the "real" answer is: move the text into a DE field and JOIN that table and field content instead of writing the full text into your query. That actually makes it maintainable without code, too.
Alternatively, fixing the symptoms only,  you can experiment with obfuscation, but this will just create new issues (encoding...) - try and insert something invisible like a zero-width non joiner in an encoding that the SMS interprets correctly. But that's a workaround, not a solution.
Untested (probably doesn't work in SMS) , but to show what I mean:
in&zwnj;to
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner

Some words are indeed not allowed to be used in the SQL Query Activity. Here is a bit more info about them:

Microsoft SQL Server uses reserved keywords for defining, manipulating, and accessing databases. Reserved keywords are part of the grammar of the Transact-SQL language that is used by SQL Server to parse and understand Transact-SQL statements and batches. Although it is syntactically possible to use SQL Server reserved keywords as identifiers and object names in Transact-SQL scripts, you can do this only by using delimited identifiers.

Reserved Keywords (Transact-SQL)

An easy workaround in your case could be splitting the word "INTO" by the Concat function -
SELECT
A.CARD_NUM AS CardNumber,
B.PHONE AS MOBILE,
CASE
    WHEN A.CATEGORY = 'KIDS BOYS' THEN 'Revamp your boys wardrobe with the latest summer collection from Boys Fashion!\nExplore trendy styles in-store or online today!'
    WHEN A.CATEGORY = 'KIDS GIRLS' THEN Concat('We invites all little queens to transform summer in', 'to a snowland with our stylish summer collection starting from just Rs.169.\nShop now!')
    ELSE 'The quantity is under 30'
END AS MESSAGE,
Concat(A.CARD_NUM, '_', 'fthh_auto', '_', Convert(VarChar, Cast(SwitchOffSet(TodateTimeOffset(GetDate(), '-06:00'), '+05:30') AS DateTime), 23)) AS UniqueKey
FROM fthh_automation_load A
INNER JOIN PRD_Contact_List B ON A.CARD_NUM = B.CARD_NUM

